# Append Query Results to Different Sheets in Excel in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using the code below to run 3 different queries in 3 different DB's 
And trying to export them to a single Excel file each result on a different sheet (9 total sheets).

But when running the code below I'm getting a file with only 3 sheets (each contain only the first query result on each DB) 
I'm using `pyodbc` for the DB connection and pandas in order to handle the Excel writing.

```
databases = {DB1, DB2, DB3}
queries = {query1, query2, query3}

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\Temp\Output.xlsx')

for database in databases:
   cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', 
                         host=database.server, 
                         database=database.db_name,
                         trusted_connection=database.trusted_connection, 
                         user=database.user_name, 
                         password=database.password)
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()

   for q in queries:
      cursor.execute(q)
      rows = cursor.fetchall()
      df = pd.read_sql_query(q, cnxn)
      df.to_excel(writer, 
                  sheet_name=str(q.index(q))+"-"+database.name)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Where does XML come into this? Anyway - instead of writing after executing each query, why not build up a single dataframe of all queries, then write?

Comment: Also - if you're using `cursor.execute` and then `rows = cursor.fetchall()` - why do you then use `pd.read_sql_query` (executing the query *again*) instead of feeding the previous stuff straight into a DataFrame?

Comment: `str(q.index(q))` this always give 0 , so are u getting sheets 0_DBNAME

Comment: @JonClements Sorry , Wrote XML instead of Excel .

Comment: @JonClements I Tried commenting the 2  in a hope that pd.read_sql_query (q, cnxn) would give what i need , but it kept getting empty Output until returning them

Comment: @RehanAzher , Isnt the Index of Q going to change every iteration of "for q in queries" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `enumerate` in inner loop to get the iterator number with variable for sheet naming.

```
...
for i, q in enumerate(queries):
  df = pd.read_sql_query(q, cnxn)
  df.to_excel(writer, 
              sheet_name=str(i+1)+"-"+database.name)
...
```

Alternatively, if *queries* is a list, you could use the `index` approach:

```
queries = [query1, query2, query3]

...
for q in queries:
  df = pd.read_sql_query(q, cnxn)
  df.to_excel(writer, 
              sheet_name=str(queries.index(q)+1)+"-"+database.name)
...
```

Comment: It worked , But i`m still not sure why index(q) does not provide me with the same thing when iterating through the queries .

Comment: I believe you intended to [index](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#index-20) a *list* but used the value of a *set*. Had queries been a list, you could use `queries.index(q)`.